# How can I display empirical pdf of my 100x1 vector data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, statistics, histogram, probability-density

I have a data which is 100x1 vector. How can I display its empirical pdf in Matlab? Also, if I want to compare the pdf of three vectors on the same graph, then how to do that?

Right now I am using [pdfplot.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8578-pdfplot) file to plot my empirical pdf, however when I want to compare the 3 distributions by using 'hold on', then firstly its not working and secondly all the distributions are in same color.  Thanks!

**EDIT:** I don't want to plot cdf.

Comment: You realize that pdfplot.m simply plots a normalized histogram with 20 bins? So - what aspect of pdfplot is important for you that isn't among the default options of hist?

Comment: Jonas: _"You realize that pdfplot.m simply plots a normalized histogram with 20 bins"_  - I didn't realize that fact :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html):

```
hist(data)
```

or, if you want more control over how it is presented, use:

```
[n,x] = hist(data);
plot(x,n,'rx-'); %# just an example, plot the pdf with red x's and a line, 
                 %# instead of bars
figure;
plot(x, cumsum(n)/sum(n)); %# plot the CDF
```

Comment: Ofri: Is there a way that I can retain my all 100 values in the vector and plot them as hist (or pdf)?

Comment: try hist(data,min(data):max(data)) or [n,x]=hist(data,min(data):max(data))

Comment: _"try hist(data,min(data):max(data)) or [n,x]=hist(data,min(data):max(data))"_  - It doesn't work. Gives _out of memory_ error.

Answer (score 12):

What you are looking for is [Kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (also known as *Parzen windows*). Its implemented in [KSDENSITY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ksdensity.html) function in the Statistics toolbox:

```
data = randn(100,1);
ksdensity(data)
```

[image]

The Wikipedia entry above has a MATLAB example using a function submission on [FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14034)